# GCP : Is there any exchangeable format to get revised price value immediately?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, components, price

We are working in one of the customer module. With the help of this module, we are calculating price for google cloud components like compute engine with attributes images, boot disk, region, snapshot etc.

But we found that GCP is revising the prices and [JSON](https://cloudpricingcalculator.appspot.com/static/data/pricelist.json) is not modifying immediately. Newly revised pricing values comes in JSON after few days.

So the price according to JSON and price in google cosole/calculator are different in this case.

***Is there any exchangeable format to get revised pricing immediately?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON file isn't exactly the ideal way to obtain pricing information anymore. In fact, the link to the JSON file was removed from the [Pricing Calculator page](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/) very recently precisely because they want people to start using the [Catalogue API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/how-tos/catalog-api). That one has the prices up-to-date for sure, so I'd recommend you to use that instead.

Comment: so sad that GCP calculator removed JSON link. thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have any idea about, catalog APIs will be there till the end? or that too will change in between?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by be there till the end? The Catalog API is the recommended way to get pricing information for GCP, and it seems to be pretty well documented.

Comment: @hubatish Thank you for quick help. But in catalog APIs, they are not providing complete information. Eg: For boot type PD-standard they are providing information only for 9 regions and total regions are 15.

Comment: @hubatish I also raised separate question for this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168732/gcp-how-to-get-disk-price-for-missing-region-in-catalog-api

Comment: 2020 and there's still no alternative to that JSON pricelist file. The new catalog-api is a joke and does not provide any way to get prices for GPUs or compute machine types. Even the official google cloud console uses still this file, so I think it's a fair bet to keep using that file. They won't remove it without providing an API that provides the same information.